# RSA number factors (is semiprime)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography, prime-factorization

I have the $n$ RSA number of a message, i need to find the $p,q$ prime factors of $n$ to find the private key.

I have $n$, and $e$. This is for a challenge and i think this number was previously factored.

Someone knows any database of sempiprimes factors or another way to find the factors (don't tell me "try to factorize it yourself", because it's too big).
Thanks for help.

You can use https://www.mobilefish.com/services/big_number/big_number.php to convert numbers to other bases.

RSA $n$(5831 bits) - 4a fa 68 5b 04 1e 1b 1b a9 5c 3a 86 d2 b4 1b bc c2 dd 0a 0f f9 0a 57 48 c8 0b 01 37 a6 3c 63 52 92 21 49 ec ea bc 92 64 24 29 64 2b 7e 9e 73 e6 80 97 85 e9 cc 34 f5 83 d9 0e d4 a3 42 a8 0d 46 c7 7f f3 65 56 5d 0c 6f 5d 04 3b 87 c6 36 33 74 74 71 80 22 9d 0b cc 94 58 1d 26 ee 5c 6c 4a 15 ab 97 be f4 5a 37 49 44 e5 86 d2 55 fd 1a 28 8b 70 c8 41 19 7d 41 31 e4 f7 99 67 83 c6 8c ea 20 c4 c8 44 b7 68 40 b0 43 85 c2 e9 df 55 c5 5d 80 d1 ac f1 30 ed 6a 44 88 1f 98 ca 23 4a 88 9e 5b 53 51 e5 b6 b7 04 34 24 49 d7 00 04 39 58 9b 8a e9 2d 26 d7 e1 44 b8 19 5d 06 f5 9d 02 2f c0 23 93 b3 07 d5 88 ee 5b 6b cf 09 a5 78 eb 74 a7 54 d1 c9 a0 5e c1 ba 1e fb 26 5d 76 70 c4 ee 82 eb 89 b3 31 04 a6 e3 48 76 8b 77 74 bb 55 02 7a a8 0d 8f f7 53 4b a2 3d 10 1a 28 86 d9 09 80 4a ee aa a3 11 01 79 ca a5 bd 9f 13 a1 4e 35 9e 8d 2b 38 91 8f b7 9c bf 02 2a 20 5a ad 3e ea 06 43 19 51 47 81 8a fb 8b b1 ce 7c a6 5c 0f f7 e0 26 ca 1c 62 21 7d 7f 12 bd 14 e5 4d 85 a5 43 eb 9c be 8d 2d a0 69 1e 1b 69 d6 7b b1 6d b6 ab 9b 6f 6b 53 c9 a3 8a 64 bc e8 f1 35 93 9d 18 0d f9 5f b8 84 ae 8b 93 2d a6 53 8a 24 e7 e2 e4 93 6e 12 9c 39 5a 8d 6c 7a ef 13 e4 44 f4 35 5f f7 ac 35 dd c8 50 9d 84 7c 9f 50 86 79 f3 ee 8f cd 12 48 5c 79 da 94 9c fc 45 57 5f d9 36 b9 d5 5b c6 6b e2 67 f7 97 6a fa cd 15 9d 02 77 d0 c0 e5 a2 36 35 af ac 76 bc 3f 4b f9 17 4d d4 7a 58 d7 42 a5 c7 47 38 17 dd fc 49 4c c0 87 53 29 26 64 9a fc d3 33 da c7 aa 5f a5 b5 40 54 fe 15 22 d8 3c e4 6a 90 9c c1 33 0a 1b 6e 6f 21 5f f7 3a fe 0f 10 01 f6 87 4c b5 ea 06 0a 0b 30 41 ee c9 0a a7 98 d5 5f 6d 25 14 f6 73 81 94 d4 9c af cd ca 41 4c 48 87 6b c5 d2 f7 e7 75 1d 15 30 eb 36 a1 f4 f5 da da 67 e0 70 07 a0 b4 46 13 61 6d de 5c f0 8b 0e 83 39 3b ad 39 57 0e f8 74 68 4f 7f a1 7e 2a ca 32 a5 ff ac 04 ec 95 db c7 82 98 df e6 de 90 ca 78 f1 bf c1 7b e6 01 b3 38 0b 95 cc f9 f4 1c 6a fb 69 58 25 63 63 40 c5 a2 19 75 de 96 86 0a 4c 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01

RSA $e$(17 bits) - 01 00 01

Comment: There is factordb.com, but it probably won't be of any help for numbers of this size.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. There is factorized, i tried other websites but the problem was the size. This is a challenge to learn some criptography, it can't bee so hard.

Comment: try to factorize it yourself - maybe they were "careless" in the prime generation and picked $p\approx q$ or $p\approx Nq$ for small $N$ or ... whatever allows standard factorization methods to succeed relatively fast

Answer (score 2):

One of the primes is $5054843$ (decimal).